# How do you rotate a Popper.js Popup?

Tags: javascript, css, rotation, popper.js

I have a slider inside a div that sets the background colour. It is positioned using Popper. I want the slider to be vertical. Neither `rotate: 90deg` nor `transform: rotate(90deg)` on the container div have any effect. Rotating the inner slider works, but only the slider is transformed, not the background. Wrapping both inside another div and rotating the background div also has no effect.